# Ошибка при запросе вставки: ORA-01400: невозможно вставить NULL

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, insert

Создается таблица последством Liquibase:

```
    databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      validCheckSum: ANY
      id: 1
      author: some
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: REG_STATUS
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: id
                  type: BIGINT
                  autoIncrement: true
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: reg_id
                  type: BIGINT
              - column:
                  name: created_on
                  type: Timestamp
              - column:
                  name: display_offset
                  type: Timestamp
              - column:
                  name: status
                  type: varchar(50)
```

Затем в нее передается Insert посредством `jdbcTemplate.update`,
либо просто запросом через консоль - результат один.

> ORA-01400: невозможно вставить NULL

Код:

```
private static final String SAVE_NEW_REG_STATUS = "insert into REG_STATUS (REG_ID, CREATED_ON, DISPLAY_OFFSET, STATUS) values (:reg_id, :created_on, :display_offset, :status)";

Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
        paramMap.put("reg_id", 100);
        paramMap.put("created_on", Timestamp.valueOf("2021-05-31 13:13:11.6469816"));
        paramMap.put("display_offset", Timestamp.valueOf("2021-05-31 13:13:11.6469816"));
        paramMap.put("status", "NEW");
        int status = jdbcTemplate.update(SAVE_NEW_REG_STATUS, paramMap);
```

Либо просто запросом:

```
INSERT INTO REG_STATUS
(REG_ID, CREATED_ON, DISPLAY_OFFSET, STATUS)
VALUES
(5000, '2021-05-31 13:13:11.6469816', '2021-05-31 13:13:11.6469816', 'NEW');
```

Ответ:

```
[23000][1400] ORA-01400: невозможно вставить NULL в ("PS_REPORT"."REG_STATUS"."ID")
```

Разве нужно специально прописывать ID? Он же должен генерироваться самостоятельно.

Comment: Был бы ID автоинкрементом - такой проблемы бы не было... а так с какого перепугу он должен генериться самостоятельно?

Comment: да я понимаю) создается таблица посредством liquibase, скрипт добавил в описание вопроса. там стоит - что автоинкремент должен быть включен

Comment: Мало ли что там где стоит - в показанном скрипте автоинкрементом даже не пахнет. Должно быть `GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1)`, или то же в упрощённом виде.

Comment: скрипт который я привел это из логов, он был сгенерирован я так понял Oracle 11 при старте приложения. почему там не было автоинкремента это хороший вопрос.

Comment: В версии 11 не было никакого автоинкримента.

Comment: @pra_soul_owl, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В версии 11g не было ещё опции автоинкремента.

Надо вручную добавить последовательность и триггер, и приложение при вставке воспримет это как автоинкремент:

```
create sequence reg_status_seq nocycle nocache;

create or replace trigger reg_status_autoinc
    before insert on reg_status for each row
begin
    if :new.reg_id is null then
        :new.REG_ID := name_of_sequence.nextval;
    end if;
end;
/
```

И всё будет работать:

```
insert into reg_status (created_on, display_offset, status) values (
    timestamp'2021-05-31 13:13:11.6469816', timestamp'2021-05-31 13:13:11.6469816', 'new');

1 row inserted.
```