# При тестировании слоя БД получаю com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, юнит-тесты, jdbc, jpa

При тестировании слоя сервися работающего с БД получаю ошибку.

конфиг.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JdbcConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "defaultHikariConfig")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
    public HikariConfig hikariConfig() {
        return new HikariConfig();
    }

    @Bean(name = "defaultDataSource")
    public DataSource defaultDataSource(@Qualifier("defaultHikariConfig") HikariConfig hikariConfig) {
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }

    @Bean(name = "defaultJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("defaultDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name = "defaultNamedParameterJdbcTemplate")
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate(
            @Qualifier("defaultJdbcTemplate") JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
    }

    @Bean
    public RegistryDao registryDao(@Qualifier("defaultJdbcTemplate") JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, @Qualifier("defaultNamedParameterJdbcTemplate") NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate) {
        return new RegistryDao(jdbcTemplate, namedParameterJdbcTemplate);
    }
}
```

класс тестирования

```
@DisplayName("RegStatusService test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@DataJpaTest
public class DevTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("defaultHikariConfig")
    private HikariConfig hikariConfig;
    private final DataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig); // * ошибка
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    RegStatusServiceImpl regStatusService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        regStatusService = new RegStatusServiceImpl(new RegistryDao(jdbcTemplate, namedParameterJdbcTemplate));
    }
```

содержание ошибки

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:77)
    at ru.rs.service.DevTest.<init>(DevTest.java:32)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:500)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassTestDescriptor.java:342)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:281)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:269)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:263)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$4(ClassTestDescriptor.java:262)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:82)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$0(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:66)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
```

Comment: Извините, но вы не разобрались с [одним вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1288231/217579), а уже задаете следующий вопрос. Думаю, тут "многопоточность" не совсем нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Извините, немного не разбираюсь в Spring, но предполагаю, что поле `hikariConfig` инициализируется после инициализации класса. `final` поля инициализируются во время этой самой инициализации и для них `hikariConfig = null`. Почему бы не воспользоваться бинами
`defaultJdbcTemplate` и `defaultNamedParameterJdbcTemplate`? Ну или на крайний случай можно код инициализации перенести в `@BeforeAll`))